# Setting the flag to stop looping combobox change event

Tags: combobox

I want to do stop loopong flag to my combobox. 
Problem is that when I am changing surname in combobox excel after a while it is stopping working. I think it is because of looping change event combobox.

My code is:

```
Private Sub ComboBox_Nazwisko_O_change()

Dim Nazwisko As String
Dim RngPesel As Range
Dim Lst As ListObject
Dim counter As Long
Dim znacznik As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

If znacznik <> ComboBox_Nazwisko_O.value Then

If ComboBox_Pesel_O.Visible = True Then
    ComboBox_Pesel_O.Visible = False
    ListBox_Pesel_O.Visible = True
End If

Techniczne.Cells(2, 14).value = 1

''Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
''
With Techniczne
    Set Lst = Techniczne.ListObjects("Tabela_Pesel")
    On Error Resume Next
    Lst.DataBodyRange.UsedRange.Select
    .Range("Tabela_Pesel").ClearContents
    Lst.DataBodyRange.Delete
End With

Nazwisko = ComboBox_Nazwisko_O.value
Set Lst = Nothing

With A_Wniosek

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")

    Set Lst = .ListObjects("Tabela_Wnioski")
    counter = Lst.Range.Rows.Count
    On Error Resume Next
    .ListObjects("Tabela_Wnioski").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Nazwisko
    Set RngPesel = Lst.AutoFilter.Range
    Set RngPesel = Lst.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 4).Resize(counter - 1, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    RngPesel.Copy Techniczne.Cells(2, 12)
    ListBox_Pesel_O.RowSource = "Tabela_Pesel"
    Lst.Range.AutoFilter
    Set Lst = Nothing
    Set RngPesel = Nothing
End With
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Odwolanie.ListBox_Pesel_O.RowSource = Techniczne.Range("Tabela_Pesel[Nr Pesel Pełnomocnik]").Address

End If

End Sub
```

Please help,
Best regards,
Jacek Antek